# Is it possible to create an account (new keypair) using PHP?

Tags: account

I don't have experience with solana yet and I have question in my work.
I see that it is possible to generate a key pair with web3.js
But is it possible to generate a new pshair with php ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can do it with the `solana-php-sdk` https://github.com/verze-app/solana-php-sdk with:

```
use Tighten\SolanaPhpSdk\Keypair;

$keypair = new Keypair();
// OR
$keypair = Keypair::generate();
```

Ripped off from the tests at https://github.com/verze-app/solana-php-sdk/blob/main/tests/Unit/KeypairTest.php

Comment: is there any documentation for this SDK? For example, how to create a seed phrase or complete a transaction?

Comment: I can't find too much info, but there's this bit in the README https://github.com/verze-app/solana-php-sdk#transactions

Comment: yes, I saw it, thx. But not in mind the ability to generate seed phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Solana uses ed25519 keypairs so if you can find a PHP library to do that, absolutely.

EDIT: Such as this one https://github.com/encedo/php-ed25519-ext

Comment: sorry, can you give an example code for creating an account using php ?